# Additional GET requests before POST request that my code isn't making

Tags: javascript, post, get

Only in production, and never on localhost, superagent seems to made additional GET request right before POST requests. This is similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723819/server-logs-showing-get-request-right-before-post-request) however that was using other software, this is simply superagent.

The client code is simple a POST request:

```
superagent
.post('/api/v1/csr/whois')
.send({
    someKey: someValue
})
.end(function(res){
    log('Whois response:', res)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Cross Origin Request Sharing.

**The additional GET requests are CORS 'pre-flight' requests**. This was fixed in node/express app using:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```